# Two different $WORKON_HOME and $PROJECT_HOME variables in .bash_profile and .bashrc files

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

For I did not have the choice, I had to set the `$WORKON_HOME` and `PROJECT_HOME` variables to different path in the `.bashrc` (local machine) and `.bash_profile` (remote machine) files.

e.g.:

In the `.bashrc` file (local):

```
export WORKON_HOME="$HOME/home-local/.virtualenvs"
export PROJECT_HOME="$HOME/home-local/venv_projects/"
```

and in the `bash_profile` one (remote):

```
export WORKON_HOME="$HOME/.virtualenvs"
export PROJECT_HOME="$HOME/venv_projects/"
```

My remote machine is mounted on my local machine under the `home-local` folder. I can not change this.

Thus, as I run most of my programs on the remote, I first need to create the virtualenv on the remote machine.

However, if I briefly want to work on my local machine, when I type `workon env`, the working directory gets changed to `$HOME/.virtualenvs` (as on the remote), instead of `$HOME/home-local/.virtualenvs`. I guess the `WORKON_HOME` and `PROJECT_HOME` variables are tied to the environment.

But is there any way to change this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have 2 different values for 1 variable. But you can switch between values. Put

```
export WORKON_HOME="$HOME/.virtualenvs"
export PROJECT_HOME="$HOME/venv_projects/"
```

into a file, for example "$HOME"/home.sh, and

```
export WORKON_HOME="$HOME/home-local/.virtualenvs"
export PROJECT_HOME="$HOME/home-local/venv_projects/"
```

into, e.g., "$HOME"/home-local.sh. Now you can do `source "$HOME"/home.sh` or `source "$HOME"/home-local.sh`. And `source` can be shortened to just `.`: `. "$HOME"/home-local.sh`.

You can create aliases or shell functions instead:

```
home_virt() {
    export WORKON_HOME="$HOME/.virtualenvs"
    export PROJECT_HOME="$HOME/venv_projects/"
}

home_local_virt() {
    export WORKON_HOME="$HOME/home-local/.virtualenvs"
    export PROJECT_HOME="$HOME/home-local/venv_projects/"
}
```

and just call `home_virt` or `home_local_virt`.